# como puedo aumentar el degrade android

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero aumentar el degrade para q el blanco este mas cerca del medio, como puedo hacer?

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="#E8E8E8"
            android:startColor="#f9f9f9"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tipo = "lineal"**

Establezca el `android:angle` para un tipo linear. Debe ser un múltiplo de 45 grados.

```
<gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:angle="0"
    android:startColor="#f6ee19"
    android:endColor="#115ede" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**tipo = "radial"**

Establezca el `android:gradientRadius` para un tipo radial. Usar `%p` significa que es un porcentaje de la dimensión más pequeña del padre.

```
<gradient
    android:type="radial"
    android:gradientRadius="10%p"
    android:startColor="#f6ee19"
    android:endColor="#115ede" />
```

[image: a]

Mas informacion en esta pregunta
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929877/how-to-make-gradient-background-in-android

Comment: muchas gracias estimado!, me sirvio tu respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Excelente, modifique un poco la traducción, saludos Bruno!

Answer (score 2):

Podrías jugar con **2 items** en vez de uno y darle el color deseado en el centro..

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#f9f9f9"
                android:centerColor="#f9f9f9"
                android:endColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:angle="0"
                />
            <size
                android:height="100dp"
                android:width="50dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:right="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:centerColor="#f9f9f9"
                android:endColor="#f9f9f9"
                />
            <size
                android:height="100dp"
                android:width="50dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Resultado:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado!.

Answer (score 0):

```
<gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#E8E8E8"
        android:startColor="#f9f9f9"
        android:centreColor="#fafafa" // Color "medio"
        android:centreX="0.7" // Dónde esta el "color medio"
        android:type="linear" />
```

Esto te dividirá el gradiente en dos partes, una de `FAFAFA` a `F9F9F9` que ocupará el 70% del gradiente, y otra de `F9F9F9` A `E8E8E8`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable

Comment: muchas gracias!!